# Partial copy of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
[[-6, 3, 9], [-7, 2, 9], [-3, 2, 5], ... , [3, 4, 1]]
```

The array that I'm using is structured like the one above.

My goal is to divide this array based upon a certain position that has been previously determined.

I've attempted `Arrays.copyOf` , `Arrays.copyOfRange`, and `System.arraycopy` - but have not experienced success, which is why I wrote my own method for this; it also didn't work.

`partitionResult` is an instance (variable) array of type `int` structured just like `arrayOfVals`

`arrayOfVals` seems to become initialized with the entire `partitionResult` array despite my intention of only copying only a portion. I have tested i.e. `System.out.println (partitionResult[begin+i][j])` , and the values printed are as desired.

```
 private int[][] copyArray(int begin, int end)
    {
        int SUBARRAY_SIZE = 2;
        // below the '+1' is due to zero-indexing
        int[][] arrayOfVals = new int[end-begin+1][SUBARRAY_SIZE+1];
        end -= begin;

        for (int i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= SUBARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
                arrayOfVals[begin][j] = partitionResult[begin+i][j];
            }
        }
        return arrayOfVals;
    }
```

Why can I not do the following as desired?

```
private void foo(int begin)
{
    int[][] arrayOne = copyArray(0, begin);
    int[][] arrayTwo = copyArray(begin+1, partitionResult.length -1);
    ...

}
```

***Edit:***

```
[[-6, 3, 9], [-7, 2, 9], [-3, 2, 5], [3, 4, 1], [0, 5, 5], [2, 3, 1], [3, 4, 1]]
```

This is my test array. 
I would like to split this array using the `copyArray` method at the defined position `begin`.

When I print the values that I'd like copied, `partitionResult[begin+i][j]`, the result is exactly as it should be; however, display the final `arrayOfVals` - the output is not what I printed, it is the entire `partitionResult` array.

I want `arrayOne` to equal `[[-6, 3, 9], [-7, 2, 9], [-3, 2, 5]]`

and    `arrayTwo` to equal `[[3, 4, 1], [0, 5, 5], [2, 3, 1], [3, 4, 1]]`

***Edit2:*** The problem was not with the method `copyArray` but with another method. 
The `toString` method that I wrote was displaying the values used by the instance variable `partitionResult` rather than the array that I passed to it - this made it seem as if nothing was being copied. The mistake should have been obvious to me. I greatly appreciate the advice.

Though, one small bug was found by @Andrea.

Comment: If your own method didn't work I'd guess you have a conceptual problem.

Comment: Any sample input with expected output? I'm not sure I understand the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I see you updated your question, thanks. If I understand it correctly, it seems like you simply want a copy of a part of your array, with the only minor detail that the elements are arrays as well. That should be simple enough, just grab the requested range of elements and clone them before putting them in the result.

Comment: `Arrays.copyOf` should work, but does not do a deep copy, that is the element `int[]` arrays are shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be simple enough, you're just making it hard for yourself by mutating `end`, making it hard to understand your loop's progression. Just copy the values between `begin` and `end` (inclusive), but make sure to clone each subarray. (The cloning effectively replaces your inner loop.)

```
private int[][] copyArray(int begin, int end) {
    // Calculate the size of the output
    // below the '+1' is due to zero-indexing
    int size = end - begin + 1;
    int[][] arrayOfVals = new int[size][];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // Clone each subarray to make sure changes to the copy
        // don't affect the internal array
        // (A shallow .clone() suffices for integer arrays)
        arrayOfVals[i] = partitionResult[begin + i].clone();
    }
    return arrayOfVals;
}
```

This gives the expected output for your sample input when calling `foo(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

The error should be in

```
 arrayOfVals[begin][j] = partitionResult[begin+i][j];
```

change it to

```
 arrayOfVals[i][j] = partitionResult[begin+i][j];
```

because your newly created array has to start inserting values from 0.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not produce the valid result. Yes, this may have been an error that I didn't realize because the current begin=0 , but the arrayOfVals still assumes all of the values rather than only those I want copied.

Answer (score 0):

if fromArray is the input array and index is the index at which you want to break input array, you could do:

```
    System.arraycopy(fromArray, 0, arrayOne, 0, index);
    System.arraycopy(fromArray, index+1, arrayTwo, 0, fromArray.length-index);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have, when you create a 2d array, is an array of arrays. Look at the problem like this:

```
[0,0]  [1,0]  [2,0] ... [n,0]
[0,1]  [1,1]  [2,1] ... [n,1]
[0,2]  [1,2]  [2,2] ... [n,2]
```

[[-6, 3, 9], [-7, 2, 9], [-3, 2, 5], ... , [3, 4, 1]]

We can represent your example data set as follows:

```
[-6]  [-7]  [-3] ... [ 3]
[ 3]  [ 2]  [ 2] ... [ 4]
[ 9]  [ 9]  [ 5] ... [ 1]
```